# Apache POI Streamsheet getRow unsupported operation exception

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I want to read more than 600k rows from an excel (.xlsx) file.

I'm using Apache POI and xlsx-streamer.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.monitorjbl</groupId>
        <artifactId>xlsx-streamer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Apache poi version is 3.15 because xlsx-streamer didn't support in above versions

I want to iterate only particular columns. What I have tried is:

```
File myFile = new File("testFile.xlsx");

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    Workbook workbook = StreamingReader.builder().bufferSize(4096).open(fis);
    // Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
        for (int r = 0; r < sheet.getLastRowNum(); r++) {
            Row rr = sheet.getRow(r);
            for (int c = 1; c < rr.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
                Cell cell = rr.getCell(c);
                System.out.println("" + cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
```

I get this exception with few warnings

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingSheet.getRow(StreamingSheet.java:102)
at ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:35)
```

Line #35 is

```
Row rr = sheet.getRow(r);
```

Comment: Which version of  xlsx-streamer are you using?

Comment: which version of java are you using ?

Comment: I have edited with the xlsx streamer version

Comment: Java  version 10.0.2

Comment: [StreamingSheet.getRow](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingSheet.java#L97) is unsupported. Only iterating over the rows of a `StreamingSheet` is possible as shown in https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader -> [Usage](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader#usage).

Comment: thank you @AxelRichter . How can I fetch data of particular column with 600k rows?

Comment: By using the `Excel Streaming Reader` as shown in [Usage](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader#usage). And then `if (c.getColumnIndex() == theColumnIndexYouNeed) ...`.

Comment: it works thank you, if you post this comment as answer, I will accept

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug about this error. [Look Here.](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61572)

You can change your java version to java 8 that can solve your problem.

Comment: Warnings are gone. But exception is still there.